# JQuery multiple toggle values

Tags: jquery, metabox, wp-admin, page-template, page-attributes

I'm trying to hide/show metaboxes dependant on the page template chosen. This has been working fine until I have come to show a metabox on more than one chosen page template.

The below code displays the Rich Content Editor for default pages, but not page-child.php pages. I'm guessing I have written the code incorrectly:

```
(function($){
    $(function() {
        $('#page_template').change(function() {
            $('#postdivrich').toggle($(this).val() == 'page-child.php') ;
            $('#postdivrich').toggle($(this).val() == 'default') ;
        }).change() ;
    }) ;
})(jQuery) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

After much pulling of hair here is the answer should anybody require it:

```
(function($){
    $(function() {
        $('#page_template').change(function() {
            $('#postdivrich').toggle($(this).val() == 'page-child.php' || $(this).val() == 'default') ;
        }).change() ;
    }) ;
})(jQuery) ;
```